# Elementh visible part

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there a way in JavaScript to get element's visible part?
E.g. I have elements that are being scrolled and I need to know whether the element is fully visible or partially and understand what part is visible.

Comment: You can use the [IntersectionObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). You can attach your listener to the desired element and have it tell you exactly when (and how much of) it is visible.